# How to join columns with same name from Different tables

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to select different tables that have the same Column e.g(Auxiliary.Categorgy, BulkContribution.Category, Expenditure.Category) name and their sum(Amount) to get a result like this.

[image]

Is there any code for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this

```
with tables_cte(Categorgy, Amount) as (
    select Categorgy, Amount from Auxiliary
    union all
    select Categorgy, Amount from BulkContribution
    union all
    select Categorgy, Amount from Expenditure)
select Categorgy, sum(Amount) Amount
from tables_cte
group by Categorgy
order by 1;
```